# Angular isolate scope confusions - functions are undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a tree-like structure with angular directives:

```
profileApp.directive('adminList', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            doc: '='
        },
        template: `

    <div class="admin-list" ng-repeat="sub in doc.subs">

        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="number" ng-model="sub.sort" ng-change="updateSort(sub, doc.subs)"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <admin-list doc="sub"></admin-list>
    </div>

        `,
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.updateSort = function(sub, array) {
                console.log('sub', sub);
                console.log('array', array);
                array.forEach(function() {

                });
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Now when I change my `input` nothing happens. If I do this "by hand" everything is fine.
Also I need to declare `updateSort()` in directive, because its' arguments are available only there.

Comment: What are you expecting it to happen when you change values in your `input`?

Comment: @tsuz updateSort() function

Comment: Can you describe a bit more on where it starts failing? What do you see `console.log('sub', sub);`? Also, is there a fiddle?